# Помогите укоротить код на JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, переменные

Не могу укоротить такой код:

```
$("#position80").click(function() {
  if ((step == true) && (position80b == false) && (position80r == false)) {
    $("#position80").css("background-color", "red");
    step = false;
    position80r = true;
    position80 = true;
    check();
  } else if ((step == false) && (position80b == false) && (position80r == false)) {
    $("#position80").css("background-color", "blue");
    step = true;
    position80b = true;
    position80 = true;
    check();
  }
});
```

Еще у меня проблема с переменными:

```
var position1 = false;
var position2 = false;
var position3 = false;
```

Их более 240

Comment: Вы бы рассказали, какую задачу решаете-то

Comment: Возможно вы видели игру на справочнике  клавиатурном тренажере  Stamina , я пытаюсь сделать то-же самое.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#position80").click(function() {
  if (!position80b && !position80r) {
    $("#position80").css("background-color", step ? "red" : "blue");
    step = !step;
    position80 = position80b = true;
    check();
    }
});
```

Для множества схожих элементов используйте массив.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#position80").click(() => {
  if (step && !position80b && !position80r)) {
    $("#position80").css("background-color", "red");
    step = false;
    position80r = true;
    position80 = true;
    check();
  } else if (!step && !position80b && !position80r) {
    $("#position80").css("background-color", "blue");
    step = true;
    position80b = true;
    position80 = true;
    check();
  }
});
```

> Это если просто укоротить, а еще лучше из этих двух блоков сделать функцию, и запускать с разными аргументами(просто код в блоках очень похож)